# Find value in array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I need to get the part of the array that is holding a specific id, so that I can use the other variables within it.

Here is my current code to create the array:

```
<?php foreach ($list_subjects as $subject): ?>
    subjects.push({
        id: parseInt(<?php echo $subject['subject_id']; ?>),
        subject_name: "<?php echo $subject['subject_name']; ?>",
        course_type: "<?php echo $subject['course_type']; ?>",
        num_videos: parseInt(<?php echo $subject['num_videos']; ?>),
        subject_tag: "<?php echo $subject['subject_tags']; ?>"
    });
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

(I know mixing PHP in this fashion isn't good practise, but bear with me for this question)

This is the code I'm using to at least try and check if the value is in the array, but it is returning -1 every time, and the value of course_id IS in the array.

> alert($.inArray(course_id, subjects.id));

Why is this happening?

Comment: jQuery, and *all JavaScript* (with the exception of [tag:node.js]) works client-side; this means the PHP is not only 'not good practice' but also entirely irrelevant to the question you're asking. Please could you show the rendered mark-up/JavaScript as seen in the browser (view source)?

Comment: Hey David, sure can:
 subjects.push({
         id: 64,
         subject_name: "ABCs",
         course_type: 1,
         num_videos: 37,
         num_badges: 9,
         num_quizzes: 59,
         subject_tag: "Subject One"
     });

Comment: Also, what would you recommend the best way of getting php array values in js would be? I know I can make ajax calls etc, but is there a way that I can get them on page load, without having to make an additional request?

Comment: You could probably use the json_encode function that's available in PHP (if you have the JSON extension enabled): http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variant of Secators function, except it works without jQuery.

```
function inArrayById(array, value) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i]["id"] === value) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work right off the bat for what I need. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

The `$.inArray(course_id, subjects.id)` part won't work, as `id` is a key of an object inside the `subjects` array (thus not a property of `subjects`). Try like that:

```
function inArrayById(array, value)
    $.each(array, function(i, element) {
        if(element.id === value){
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}

alert( inArrayById(subjects, course_id) )
```

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a whirl. Do I have to use an each loop though?

Comment: Haha nothing, I just wouldn't mind being able to do it with a variable for re-use. I guess I can just re-used the function you just wrote up?

Comment: I gave it a go. It seems to only return false.

Comment: Did you pass course_id as number and not string? Are you sure the object you're looking for is in the array? Because Secator's code is correct, and it's a very basic loop.

Comment: Well instead of using that variable, I just passed in a number directly that I know is in the array, and, still false.

Comment: There are two mistakes in this one: first it should be if(element === value) instead of using element.id, and second it will always return false because true is being returned inside the closure and has no effect on the function itself; instead a flag such as var found = false should be used to correctly return the result. With that fixed it will work. (also imho a more appropiate name for the function would be something like findValueInObject or isValueInObject)

Comment: Other than that, I'd personally suggest to use this variant instead of the accepted answer since it would be more flexible (you can check for anything, not just the id)